# Xcode issue? Dictionary in an object shows all values as false in the variables inspector, while values are actually true?

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct TestStruct: Decodable {
        var dict: [String: Bool]?
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let json = """
        {"dict":{
            "test": true
        }}
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let product = try? decoder.decode(TestStruct.self, from: json)
        print(product)
    }
}
```

With this snippet of code, the "test" value of the dict dictionary should be true. If you put a breakpoint on print(product) (Breakpoint is not on print, but I did a stepover in the screenshot), and look at the variables values in the bottom left variable inspector,

[image]

dict    [String : Bool]?    1 key/value pair    some
[0] (key: String, value: Bool)
key String  "test"
value   Bool    false

the value is set to false.

However, when we use po to access the value, the value seems to be properly set to true:

```
 Optional<TestStruct>
  ▿ some : TestStruct
    ▿ dict : Optional<Dictionary<String, Bool>>
      ▿ some : 1 element
        ▿ 0 : 2 elements
          - key : "test"
          - value : true
```

We were wondering what was going on here? Why is po product returning the good value for it's containing dictionary, while the GUI variable inspector says it's set to false.

We are using Xcode 10.1 for the test project.

Comment: The breakpoint is _not_ on the `print` statement. It is on the _previous_ statement. In particular, it is _before_ the previous statement.

Comment: Oops my bad, I did jump to the step after the breakpoint in the screenshot! I'll update the screenshot to clarify

Comment: That seems like a bug in lldb's data formatters.  I can't reproduce it in a simple project that looks like your screenshot, but if have a project that shows it, please file a bug with http://bugs.swift.org or http://bugreporter.apple.com.